# Browse an array of strings in a TextView

Tags: android, arrays, textview

I wonder how I could navigate between the strings within an array, using the previous and next buttons, these strings will be displayed in a TextView. Thank you!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.activity_f3);
    setTitleFromActivityLabel (R.id.title_text);

    TextView cumulos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cumulos);
    TextView respostas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.respostas);

    Random randPhrase = new Random();
    String[] cum = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cumulos);
    String[] resp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.resp_cumulos);

    String textout = "";
    String textresp = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < cum.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < resp.length; j++) {
            textresp = resp[j];
        }
        textout = cum[i];
    }

    cumulos.setText(textout);
    respostas.setText(textresp);
}
```

Comment: What previous and next buttons? I don't see any in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare one int for index starting with 0 then in NextButton do

```
if(!index > resp.length-1 )  //not greater than array length
{
setText(resp[index++]);
}
else { nextButton.setEnabled(false); nextButton.setClicable(false); } //not clickable anymore
```

in PreviousButton do

```
if(!index < 0)
{
   setText(resp[index--]);
}
else{
prevButton.setEnabled(false); 
prevButton.setClicable(false);
}
```

Something like this? Mind this code is not tested, might throw exceptions.
It just to give you an idea.

Comment: And add the missing parts on your own ;) I was too lazy to write all of them.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a next button and set an onClickListener for your button to navigate through the array.  Lets say you also have a previous and next button. Try this:

```
Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourNextbutton);
Button btnPrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourPreviousbutton);
int i = 0;
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View arg0) {
          if(i<cum.length-1){
               i+=1;
               cumulos.setText(cum[i]);
               respostas.setText(resp[i]);
          }

     }


});
btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

     public void onClick(View arg0) {
          if(i>0){
               i-=1;
               cumulos.setText(cum[i]);
               respostas.setText(resp[i]);
          }

     }


});
```

Comment: This all would go in your onCreate() method.